# Python как округлить число без округления последней цифры

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = 10.19
print(round(x, 1))
```

Ответ будет `10.2`.

Как сделать так, чтобы ответ был `10.1`?
То есть не округлить, а обрезать.

Comment: как вариант: `int(x * 10) / 10`

Comment: Здравствуйте, отметьте, пожалуйста, подошедший вам ответ галочкой. Так другие пользователи будут видеть что рабочий ответ на ваш вопрос был дан и не будут перебирать все, которые здесь даны.

Comment: `round(x - 0.05, 1)`.

Answer (score 5):

Самый простой вариант:

```
x = float(input())   # Запрос ввода числа
res = x * 100 // 10  # Умножаем на 100 и делим на 10 чтобы откинуть остаток
res = res / 10       # Делим на 10 чтобы получилось нужно число
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант до кучи. Чуть понятнее, мне кажется, чем несколько делений.

```
import math

x = 10.19
print(math.floor(x * 10) / 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float("{0:.1f}".format(10.19))
```

> ```
> 10.1
> ```

Comment: Нет, результат будет всё равно `10.2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = float(str(x).split('.')[0] + '.' + str(x).split('.')[1][:1]) # [:1]-количество знаков после .
```

Comment: конвертация туда-сюда довольно затратная операция

Answer (score 0):

Округлить число x до одной десятой без округления последней цифры

```py
    x = 10.19
    rounded_x = float(str(x)[:4])
    print(rounded_x)

    результат:
    10.1
```

Сам сегодня голову сломал

Ещё вариант с использованием библиотеки Decimal
С контролируемым округлением в меньшую сторону

```py
     from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_DOWN
   ...: 
   ...: x = Decimal(10.1997)
   ...: formatted_x = x.quantize(Decimal('0.0'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
   ...: print(formatted_x)
10.1
```

[docs_decimal_round](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#rounding-modes)

Comment: А если число больше 100 или меньше 10, то будет неверный результат.

Answer (score -1):

У функции `round()` есть ещё один аргумент. Он показывает до какого количества знаков после запятой следует округлять:

```
round(10.19, 1)
```

Comment: Он округлиться до 10.2 ,а мне нужно до 10.1 ,прочти ещё раз вопрос